# Watch all anchors on a page using angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, watch

I have a requirement to watch all anchors on my page. If a customer clicks on any link I need to identify this link, see if it'll open a new tab (`target="_blank"`) or do something else.

What is the best solution to handle this in Angular? In jQuery this is fairly easy but I have no idea on how to handle it in Angularjs. I tried to use `scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', ...)` on different levels but it never gets triggered. I'm now trying to make it work using

```
scope.$watch(function () {
    return angular.element('a');
}, function (value) {});
```

but that also doesn't work.

Is there any way to have the same behavior as I get in jquery with `$('a').live('click', ...)`?

Also note that it needs to be generic, so preferably it should be in a directive that is added once at a high enough level that it watches all elements (again, like is possible in jQuery). Yes, it is a hard requirement, no discussion possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should create a new directive named `a`. this way angular will execute it for all anchor

```js
angular.module('link', [])
  .directive('a', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E'
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.on('click', function() {
            if (attrs.target)
            //your logic
          })
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: angular does that already with htmlAnchorDirective, wouldn't it clash?

Comment: Oh eM Gee, of course. I'm doing that already with input. Fail on my side. I'll just add the directive so the file that gets added if a project needs it. I'm going to try it now.

Comment: @Luca it wont clash.... if there are multiple directives with same name.. angular does run them all. thats have they have improved the basic html `input` elements